# Router for small apartment

Tags: wifi, wireless, networking, router

I recently bought a Netgear X6 Nighthawk R8000 AC3200 router. It is a piece of crap. I'm looking for a non-expensive replacement for this router. I live in a small apartment sharing the WiFi spectrum with 7+ other networks. I'm looking for one with a strong signal and 802.11ac that will not be interrupted from other people's networks.

Comment: If your airwaves are congested, they will be whatever wireless router you buy. I would suggest that you make sure that you have the AC3200 configured correctly before you bin it. Unfortunately, we don't deal with support requests on this stack. The folks on [Super User](https://superuser.com/) may be able to help you. Aternatively, you could try [ThinkBroadband](http://forums.thinkbroadband.com). They are UK based, but wireless problems are the same here as anywhere.

Comment: This question is quite broad. There are many routers out there that fulfill your requirements. Can you edit your question to include anything else to narrow down the possibilities? What might help the most is telling us _why_ you think the Nighthawk is a "piece of crap". That way, we can find products that address these issues. Also, please let you know the maximum price you are willing to spend on a replacement. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go with the Ubiquity UAP-AC-PRO-US access point since my modem is a router and I can just literally connect to it.